# c# winforms organize data layer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, architecture, software-design

Am starting new big modular project which will have about 30 modules and it will use `MySQL` database. My idea is to separate modules in new projects. 
All module project will it use `MVP` pattern.

`Domain` layer am using for storing `Entities` (e.g.) `User`, `Product`, `Catogory` information about fields.

`DBA` layer am using only for `Repositories` where i will call `CUID` methods.

**My questions is:**

1. Does is okay to use repository with domain layer without using EntityFramework? All examples what i read is with EF. Can i avoid that and is that good practice ?

I create repository inteface for all repositories:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(Int64 id);

    void Create(T entity);   
    void Update(T entity);  
    void Delete(T entity);
}
```

And simple `Product` repository

```
public class ProductRepository : Base.IBaseRepository<Product>
{
    public void Create(Product entity)
    {
        //
    }

    public void Delete(Product entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Product GetById(long id)
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable";
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // etc ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Update(Product entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Does this good practice for big project? Can you suggest me what can edit for future program.
I want to create realy good project structure, all comments are welcome.

[image]

Comment: EF is a technology stack for handling databases, such as MySQL in your case. The repository should handle the database handling itself, no matter what frameworks or technologies you will use. Your domain can expose the repository contracts, such as interfaces but what happens inside the repository implementation has nothing to do with the domain. So, in short, using EF or not inside the repository is a decision that you must make by the needs of your project. About your 2nd question, how BIG is your definition of big project?

Comment: I’d also suggest you look into using ORMs/microORMs, e.g. PetaPOCO, Dapper etc... save you some sql handcrafting.

Comment: @rm.szc81 This project will be expanden in future. It will be contain about 30 modules. Its `ERP Sistem` whit ill include `POS communcation`, `Payments`, all `Retail managment` etc... For that i want to make good start project structure.t hat I have no problem in the future, eazy to update somthing if clint want.